# FPX payment gateway integration

Tags: .net

i am creating the web application in ASP.net ,i have to integrate FPX payment gateway in it .i am having keys for the integration.can any body guide me how the transaction details will be passed to FPX, is tat done via web API call? can anybody say how the data will be passed , in asp.net how to implement those Web API call

Comment: If you want to accept payments with FPX and many other payment methods through Stripe, check out https://easypie.shop/ - Shopping, Payment and Subscription Terminal